# libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cilk, cilk-plus

I want to run Cilkscreen command with a cilk++ program but I'v got this error

> /usr/local/cilk/bin/../lib32/pinbin: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Can you help me please

Answer (score 247):

Try this:

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: This is *much* better than installing ia32-libs (as proposed by trion). Doing this, I had to install 1 or 2 other dependencies while ia32-libs has 241 dependencies totaling 267 MB additional disk space.

Comment: This also works to run the Microsoft Windows virtual appliances for testing self-extracting program. Thanks!

Comment: @takeit For a 64bit machine, should we install `lib64stdc++6` instead ?

Comment: @boddhisattva I think [`lib32stdc++6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/lib32stdc++6) is for 64bit machine running 32bit software. Something similar to "compatibility layer". To run 64bit ("native") software on 64bit machine you just need [`libstdc++6`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libstdc++6). (The links are for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr; I cannot find the link for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat.)

Comment: Awesome, though I met this problem in a different situation where I try to build android source code, it figured out the problem perfectly. Thank you so so much!!!ls

Answer (score 15):

I presume you're running Linux on an amd64 machine.
The Folder your executable is residing in (`lib32`) suggests a 32-bit executable which requires 32-bit libraries.

These seem not to be present on your system, so you need to install them manually. 
The package name depends on your distribution, for Debian it's `ia32-libs`, for Fedora `libstdc++.<version>.i686`.

Comment: I'm running Linux on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Then you want to do it the Debian way and install `ia32-libs` or switch to a 64-bit version of the software you're trying to use.

Comment: I was installed this package but I'v got now another error "process killed by signal -7
E:Attach to pid 3874 failed: Operation not permitted"

Comment: Looks like you're trying to attach a 64-bit debugger/monitor to a 32-bit application or vice versa?
You should really try to get 64-bit components and create 64-bit executables; this will make life much easier.

Comment: How can I do this ? I'm a Linux beginner and I don't understand you well how to attach a 64-bit debugger/monitor to a 32-bits application o v/s. can you explain that please

Comment: I haven't used Cilk before, so I'm afraid I can't really help you with that. Search Google for 64-bit versions of Cilk or start a new thread on this topic ("Using Cilk on 64-bit systems").

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This solved for me on Debian 6 "squeeze": `$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 11):

For Red Hat :

```
sudo yum install libstdc++.i686
sudo yum install libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Answer (score 9):

For Fedora use:

`yum install libstdc++44.i686`

You can find out which versions are supported by running:

`yum list all | grep libstdc | grep i686`

Answer (score 1):

/usr/local/cilk/bin/../lib32/pinbin is dynamically linked to a library libstdc++.so.6 which is not present anymore.  You need to recompile Cilk

Comment: but libstdc++.so.6  exists in /usr/lib folder

Comment: Yes, but as it's a 32-bit application, it requires `/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6`.